# Is a general question discussing differences in research methodology in different fields too broad?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, too-broad

This question pertains to the issue raised from this [post](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/88320/differences-in-the-culture-of-writing-and-publishing-papers-in-various-fields). I basically asked a question about the differences in generating ideas, writing and publishing an academic journal in different fields. I thought this question was suitable for Academia SE because it is on-topic, and it may help others who may wonder on this question. However, this question is now on the verge of being closed with 4 votes, because it is too broad.

I've included my sample answer for the field of Economics, and I doubt that it is too broad that it is unanswerable, as exemplified by many comments and my own answer. How can I change the question to make it more specific, or can someone explain why it may be too broad? Or are questions that asked about differences in various fields not welcomed in Academia SE?

Answer (score 4):

Your original question contains

> I'd like to see how this process may differ in various fields.

In this question you say

> I've included my sample answer for the field of Economics

It sounds like you are envisioning an answer for each (or many) fields. These are generally *big-list* questions and are covered, indirectly, on the [don't ask](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) page. Basically, you should avoid asking question where *every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”* While your question is not asking for a favorite, all the answers will be equally valid.

If the question was phrased to be looking for a single answer, that answer would be too long (and hence too broad) since it would have to encompass all fields, their histories and comparisons. Asking for a single comparison of related fields can be beneficial, but also may be too technical. For example, EE and CS people often take different approaches (and value different outcomes) despite often being housed in the same department. A question asking about comparing those fields would be on topic in my opinion. Similarly, although completely outside my expertise, asking about differences between economics and political science (or any other related field) would potentially be on topic.

While it seems circular, the question needs to be specific, but still broad enough to apply to academia in general, and it cannot be so specific that it is better answered in a field specific SE. This can be difficult, but read through our past questions and you will see it can be done.

Comment: Your understanding of my intention is completely on spot. I was asking for answers that would be equally valid, and I understand that it's not a good question. I'd then think that this question is not really suitable for Academia SE. What do you do in this case, especially since someone has posted an answer? Do you just leave it to be closed, or do you delete the question?

Comment: @Hosea having strict rules about the type of questions we allow makes SE the place to go to get good information, but it can also makes asking good questions difficult. That is why we have our [help] (and chat and meta).  Since there is an upvoted answer on your question, you cannot delete it, as that would destroy the work that someone else did. High rep users periodically look at closed questions and either try and edit them to fit or delete them. Don't worry about have a close question floating around, you have asked a bunch of good question (and hopefully gotten some good answers).